# gitlab remove read permission from protected branches

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab 8.10.0 version. I am using protected branched feature since a long time.

Now we have setup gitlab continues deployment, in which we have to provide server credentials information in .yml file.

**I want to remove even read permission from protected branches, only some people can have it.**

Is it possible with gitlab, because I am not finding any solution in the interface?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the read permission from the protected branch or all branches?

Comment: just from protected branches would be work

Answer (score 1):

Individual branch visibility can't be configured in GitLab because it is not how git works. The only way to deny read access is to give that user Guest access or set your project to Internal and remove the user from the Group or Project entirely.